# Actions on Google - Failed to parse SDKResponse

Tags: actions-on-google

```
{
"response": "my test app isn’t responding right now. Try again soon.\n",
"audioResponse": "//NExAAR0...",
"debugInfo": {
    "sharedDebugInfo": [
        {
            "name": "ExecutionResponse",
            "debugInfo": "Failed to parse SDKResponse from http_response: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nX-Powered-By: Express\r\nContent-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 258\r\nETag: W/\"102-WOnideDlHzFAk9nQQ/VU8SUGeMY\"\r\nDate: Thu, 25 May 2017 10:39:15 GMT\r\n\r\n{\"conversation_token\":\"{\\\"state\\\":null,\\\"data\\\":{}}\",\"expect_user_response\":true,\"expected_inputs\":[{\"input_prompt\":{\"initial_prompts\":[{\"ssml\":\"<speak>Hello.</speak>\"}],\"no_input_prompts\":[]},\"possible_intents\":[{\"intent\":\"assistant.intent.action.TEXT\"}]}]}'"
        }
    ]
},
"visualResponse": {}
}
```

I got this from Web Simulator when try to send back JSON response to Action On Google. I don't want to use ActionsSdkAssistant node module, but try to get the same results as ask() method from this module.

Comment: Can you include the JSON that you think you are sending back? Including the code you're using to build the entire response may also be helpful.

Comment: Without more info, such as your json response, it will be impossible to give any guidance.  Why not use the SDK?  There is also this SDK for Java/Kotlin if you using the JVM - https://github.com/TicketmasterMobileStudio/actions-on-google-kotlin